# Erase method and comparing pixel colors on the Android framework

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-color

Reading the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#eraseColor(int)) I stumbled upon a useful `eraseColor` method. 
Since its description says:

> Fills the bitmap's pixels with the specified Color.

I thought that the snippet below should have printed `OK`. Unfortunately it was not the case.

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
if (bitmap.getPixel(0, 0) == Color.WHITE)
    System.out.println("OK");
else 
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
```

What am I missing?